# Redux Reducer - State

Tags: redux

So I'm just getting started with redux.I am trying to fetch some gifs from an API.
My goal is to return an array of img urls instead of the whole response data.However if I try to iterate and return each image my state remains null.If I use `return action.payload.data.data;` which returns the whole response then this works but I only want to get the img urls.
Here is the corresponding reducer.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
export default function(state = null,action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_GIF':
    _.forOwn(action.payload.data.data, function(value, key) {
      var img = value.images.downsized.url;
      return img;
    });  
      // return action.payload.data.data;
      default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

state = null looks a bit wrong, it should normally default to some kind of initialState object. Then in your case block it's not really clear what the _.forOwn is supposed to return. Are you trying to mutate action.data.data? If so, maybe check if that is actually happening. Also your state returned by the reducer should be an object, I don't think redux works when you return an array.

Comment: Well,first of all I made a typo. action.data.data is actually action.payload.data.data which returns an array of objects.Each object is related to a gif.But I only need the gif url from each object so my objective is to return an array or object for that matter, of gif urls.